# The new way to synchronize with time is systemd-timesyncd. What is the replacement for `ntpq -p`?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, ntp

With `ntp`, I could run `ntpq -p` to see the current status of the clock precision. Is there an equivalent with the new `systemd-timesyncd` service?

I looked at the `timedatectl` command, it gives me these options:

```
$ timedatectl --help
timedatectl [OPTIONS...] COMMAND ...

Query or change system time and date settings.

  -h --help                Show this help message
     --version             Show package version
     --no-pager            Do not pipe output into a pager
     --no-ask-password     Do not prompt for password
  -H --host=[USER@]HOST    Operate on remote host
  -M --machine=CONTAINER   Operate on local container
     --adjust-system-clock Adjust system clock when changing local RTC mode

Commands:
  status                   Show current time settings
  set-time TIME            Set system time
  set-timezone ZONE        Set system time zone
  list-timezones           Show known time zones
  set-local-rtc BOOL       Control whether RTC is in local time
  set-ntp BOOL             Enable or disable network time synchronization
```

Maybe there is a file somewhere I can look at?

I was expecting to see at least some data like this:

```
$ sudo ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 monster         .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ntp.ucdavis.edu 128.9.176.30     2 u    4   64    1   19.383  -19.799   0.000
 45.207.161.200  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 time-b-wwv.nist .NIST.           1 u    3   64    1   46.721    2.287   0.000
 198.255.68.106  172.89.18.234    2 u    3   64    1   29.467    0.775   0.000
 euphoric.ca     128.233.154.245  2 u    3   64    1   55.963    2.732   0.000
 user-69-1-1-251 216.239.35.0     2 u    3   64    1  106.202   11.649   0.000
 tick.chi1.ntfo. 206.55.64.77     3 u    4   64    1   61.316   -3.556   0.000
```

Comment: It is only the new way on distributions that use systemd.

Comment: @fpmurphy Yeah, I use Ubuntu... hence the tag.

Comment: I can't check it out right now, but the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-timesyncd.service.html) says "*timedatectl(1)'s **timesync-status** or **show-timesync** command can be used to show the current status of this service.*"

Comment: Besides, `systemd-timesyncd` is not a full replacement for `ntpd` or `chrony`, since it can't be used as an NTP server. You can still install them, though. I seem to remember that `systemd-timesyncd` automatically disables itself when it sees that one of the full NTP servers is present.

Comment: @berndbausch I've seen instances where `ntpd` is not running and I was thinking that could happen because port 123 is already in use (according to the error I've seen, which says it can't bind and then `ntpd` dies forever). But it sounds like `system-timesyncd` is really not precise enough so I should certainly continue to use `ntpd`.

Comment: SNTPv4 (see RFC2030) - which `system-timesyncd` uses - is by design not  as accurate/precise as NTP even though it uses the same protocol message.  By disregarding drift values and using simplified system clock adjustment methods (often simple time stepping), an SNTP client can only achieve a low quality time synchronization when compared with a NTP client.

Comment: @AlexisWilke you should give chrony a try, as it is supposed to replace ntp and has commands like `chronyc sources` and `chronyc sourcestats` which give detailed output like you asked for.

Comment: `ntpd` is the original NTP implementation, but it seems to be buggy, hard to understand (for developers) and with security holes after decades of adding code. `chronyd` is smaller, neater and more secure, from what I have gathered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of `timedatectl` has two sub-commands which can be used to display information about the `system-timesyncd` SNTP (Simple Network Time Protocol) client service.

An SNTP client is much simpler and more minimalist than an NTP client because it bypasses various steps, does not save as much synchronization information, and only periodically adjusts the system time, and is thus less accurate. `ntpq` does not work with SNTP.

```
# timedatectl timesync-status -a
       Server: 162.159.200.1 (0.fedora.pool.ntp.org)
Poll interval: 4min 16s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)    
         Leap: normal                               
      Version: 4                                    
      Stratum: 3                                    
    Reference: A230E10                              
    Precision: 1us (-25)                            
Root distance: 24.711ms (max: 5s)                   
       Offset: -609us                               
        Delay: 36.883ms                             
       Jitter: 211.500ms                            
 Packet count: 384                                  
    Frequency: +10.723ppm

# timedatectl show-timesync -a
LinkNTPServers=
SystemNTPServers=
FallbackNTPServers=0.fedora.pool.ntp.org 1.fedora.pool.ntp.org 2.fedora.pool.ntp.org 3.fedora.pool.ntp.org
ServerName=0.fedora.pool.ntp.org
ServerAddress=162.159.200.1
RootDistanceMaxUSec=5s
PollIntervalMinUSec=32s
PollIntervalMaxUSec=34min 8s
PollIntervalUSec=4min 16s
NTPMessage={ Leap=0, Version=4, Mode=4, Stratum=3, Precision=-25, RootDelay=48.660ms, RootDispersion=381us, Reference=A230E10, OriginateTimestamp=Thu 2021-02-18 04:47:25 GMT, ReceiveTimestamp=Thu 2021-02-18 04:47:25 GMT, TransmitTimestamp=Thu 2021-02-18 04:47:25 GMT, DestinationTimestamp=Thu 2021-02-18 04:47:26 GMT, Ignored=no PacketCount=384, Jitter=211.500ms }
Frequency=702740
#
```

If you want to continuously monitor the status of the `systemd-timesyncd` service, you can use `timedatectl timesync-status --monitor`.

You can display individual properties of the `systemd-timesyncd` service by using the `--property=` or `-p` option. For example:

```
# timedatectl show-timesync -p ServerName
ServerName=0.fedora.pool.ntp.org
#
```

Comment: That works in 20.04, but not 18.04, hence my question. I would think that the data is available somewhere and the interface in 18.04 doesn't yet give you easy access to it. The problem for me would be to find out where that data resides. If only in the service (i.e. in memory) then I guess we don't have access...

Comment: @AlexisWilke.  A critical detail missing from your question!

Comment: Oh! Good catch. I would have sworn I put that detail in there.